# how to use Parallel SSH with Amazon EC2 instances?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to run an Parallel SSH with Amazon Instances, But I am getting Permission denied expception, How ever I can SSH it to the server. How we can run PSSH with key login. So far I have tried like,

```
pssh -h hosts-file -i xxx.pem -l username date
```

Answer (score 14):

use the -x argument.

Example

```
pssh  -i  -H ubuntu@xxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com  -x "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i /home/ccc/xxx/something-us-east.pem" 'echo hi'
```

Whatever u put in -x gets passed as arguments to the underlying ssh process.

Answer (score 9):

The `-i` parameter of [parallel-ssh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/parallel-ssh.1.html) doesn't specify the keyfile like it does for `ssh`. You need to add something like this to your `~/.ssh/config` to get SSH to use the right keyfile.

```
Host *.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ec2.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you can ssh to each of these instances using ssh and ensure that the same xxx.pem works for all instances. Once you do that, the pssh command will work. You may have to copy your public key to each instance and add an entry to the .ssh/authorized_keys file.